# Shader code to show selected part of image - OpenTk

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, opentk

I want to show selected area from second half of an image (This is the range from 0.5 to 1.0) in my glcontrol. For that I have used two variables  rightsliderStartval(any value between 0.5 and 1.0)
and rightsliderEndval(any value between 1.0 and 0.5). I want exactly the selected area between this rightsliderStartval and rightsliderEndval. When        trying like below selected area is getting but it get stretched.

```
  decimal RateOfResolution = (decimal)videoSource.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Width / (decimal)videoSource.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Height;          
  int openGLwidth = (this._Screenwidth / 3) - 40;  
  int openGLheight = Convert.ToInt32(screenWidthbyThree / RateOfResolution); 
  glControl.Width = openGLwidth;
  glControl.Height = openGLheight;
  GL.Viewport(new Rectangle(0, 0, glControl.Width, glControl.Height));


 public void CreateShaders()
 {
/***********Vert Shader********************/
vertShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
GL.ShaderSource(vertShader, @"attribute vec3 a_position;
    varying vec2 vTexCoordIn; 

    void main() {
        vTexCoordIn=( a_position.xy+1)/2 ;
        gl_Position = vec4(a_position,1);
    }");
GL.CompileShader(vertShader);

/***********Frag Shader ****************/
fragShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
GL.ShaderSource(fragShader, @"precision highp float;

    uniform sampler2D sTexture;
    varying vec2 vTexCoordIn;
    void main ()
    {
        vec2 vTexCoord=vec2(vTexCoordIn.x,vTexCoordIn.y);
        float rightsliderStartval=0.6;//0.5 to 1.0
        float rightsliderEndval=0.8;//1.0 to 0.5
        float rightsliderDelta=rightsliderEndval-rightsliderStartval;

     if (vTexCoordIn.x < 0.5)
     discard;
    float u = mix(rightsliderStartval, rightsliderEndval, (vTexCoordIn.x-0.5) * 2.0);

   vec4 color = texture2D(sTexture, vec2(u, vTexCoordIn.y));
   gl_FragColor = color;


    }");
GL.CompileShader(fragShader);
   }
```

In Screenshot, White line represent center of image. I Want to show area between yellow and orange line.
[image: White line represent center of image. Want to show area between yellow and orange line]

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip a some parts of the texture, then you can use the [`discard`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Special_operations) keyword. This command causes the fragment's output values to be discarded and the fragments are not drawn at all.

If you've a rectangular area and you want to draw only in the 2nd half of the rectangular area, then you've to discard the fragments in the 1st half:

```c
if (vTexCoordIn.x < 0.5)
    discard;
```

If you want to draw the range from `rightsliderStartval` to `rightsliderEndval` in the 2nd half of the rectangular area, then you have to map the rang [0.5, 1.0] incoming texture coordinate `vTexCoordIn.x` to [rightsliderStartval,  rightsliderEndval]:

```c
float w = (vTexCoordIn.x-0.5) * 2.0;                      // [0.5, 1.0] -> [0.0, 1.0]
float u = mix(rightsliderStartval, rightsliderEndval, w); // [0.0, 1.0] -> [0.7, 0.9]
```

This leads to the fragment shader:

```c
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D sTexture;
varying vec2 vTexCoordIn;

void main ()
{
    float rightsliderStartval = 0.7;
    float rightsliderEndval   = 0.9;

    if (vTexCoordIn.x < 0.5)
        discard;

    float u = mix(rightsliderStartval, rightsliderEndval, (vTexCoordIn.x-0.5) * 2.0);

    vec4 color = texture2D(sTexture, vec2(u, vTexCoordIn.y));
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

---

If you don't want that the image is stretched then you've 2 possibilities.

Either discard the region from 0.0 to 0.7 and 0.9 to 1.0:

```c
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D sTexture;
varying vec2 vTexCoordIn;

void main ()
{
    float rightsliderStartval = 0.7;
    float rightsliderEndval   = 0.9;

    if (vTexCoordIn.x < 0.7 || vTexCoordIn.x > 0.9)
        discard;

    vec4 color = texture2D(sTexture, vTexCoordIn.xy));
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Or scale the image in the y direction, too:

```c
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D sTexture;
varying vec2 vTexCoordIn;

void main ()
{
    float rightsliderStartval = 0.7;
    float rightsliderEndval   = 0.9;

    if (vTexCoordIn.x < 0.5)
        discard;

    float u = mix(rightsliderStartval, rightsliderEndval, (vTexCoordIn.x-0.5) * 2.0);

    float v_scale = (rightsliderEndval - rightsliderStartval) / 0.5;
    float v = vTexCoordIn.y * v_scale + (1.0 - v_scale) / 2.0;;

    vec4 color = texture2D(sTexture, vec2(u, v));
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Comment: It is working but area between selected range seems to be stretched. and tried by putting above code in a if loop. if (vTexCoordIn.x <= 1.0 &&  vTexCoordIn.x > 1.0-(rightsliderDelta*2.0)){} now works better but still have a stretch and   zoom effect. pls help

Comment: @user2431727 Ypu've to be more specific. Do you just want to discard the area at the left and the right? What is the aspect ration of the area in compared to the aspect ration of the image?

Comment: pls check my edited ques.  attached what i'm getting when trying with your code. I want the area between yellow  and orange line

Comment: pls check my edited ques. attached what i'm getting when trying with current code(. I want the full area between yellow and orange line

Comment: @user2431727 I've absolutely no idea what you want to do. I've the feeling every time when I try to answer your question you come around with something completely new. What do you want to show? The second half? This is the range form 0.5 to 1.0. The range from 0.7 to 0.9? Then it will get stretched, but you don't want to get it stretched. Do you want to scale it in both directions (x and y)? What is the size of the rectangle area which is drawn and what should be drawn in this area? It is not possible to answer this question.

Comment: @user2431727 Again i tried to guess what you want to do. See the 3rd part of the answer.

Comment: Extremely sorry to know that the way I asked was unclear. please check my edited question now. .

Comment: @user2431727 *"When trying like below selected area is getting but it get stretched."* - Yes of course it is streched. You want that the image area from 0.7 to 0.9 fills the right half, but it should not be stretched. How should that work? That is not possible. Should the image be scaled in the y direction too? Or should the range from 0.5 to 0.7 and 0.9 to 1.0 be discarded?

Comment: Or should the range from 0.5 to 0.7 and 0.9 to 1.0 be discarded?  - yes . Can I overcome this stretch by resiziing glcontrol ?

Comment: @user2431727 Yes, you've to scale the the width of the glcontrol: `new_width = int(width * (0.9-0.7)/0.5)`

Comment: Can you  please help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57033603/apply-projection-on-other-than-discarded-area